# I am trying to link images to constant contact

Tags: linux, url, path, constants, contacts

I am trying to link images to constant contact from my linux server. The images are stored in a folder on my linux server as I have done previous on my windows server. The path I use from the windows server works fine but the path on the linux server does not.

I added the folders to the root of the drive and dropped the jpg's in the folder. So this is what works on the Windows Server http://www.mydomainname.com/folder/folder/image_name.jpg. This doesn't work on the linux server. Any help out there is very much appreciated.

Comment: What directory did you put them in? By "root directory", do you mean the HTTP server's document root?